# Check if a value is of an empty type

Tags: javascript

A field is considered "empty" if one of the following conditions are true:

- The value is `null`.
- The value is an empty string (`""` or `''`).
- The value is an empty array (`[]`).
- The value is `undefined`
- The value is an empty object (`{}`)

Values such as `false` or `0` must not be considered empty.

How do I check if the value is empty
eg:

```
function isEmpty(value){
   //code

   return bool
}

console.log("False Cases:")
console.log(isEmpty('A')) //false
console.log(isEmpty(false)) //false
console.log(isEmpty(true)) //false
console.log(isEmpty(0)) //false
console.log(isEmpty(["test"])) //false
console.log(isEmpty({"test": "test"})) //false
console.log("True Cases:")
console.log(isEmpty({})) //true
console.log(isEmpty('')) // true
console.log(isEmpty(null)) //true
console.log(isEmpty()) //true
console.log(isEmpty([])) //true
console.log(isEmpty(undefined)) //true
```

**Edit:**
I've included test results that must pass as the above

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: fixed it, my bad

Comment: You almost wrote the code yourself in the question.

Comment: I did manage to write it myself, but I want to see if there's any shortcuts or more efficient ways @danh

Comment: @Albert updated by answer  to match your test cases

Comment: how is `console.log(isEmpty({"test": "test"}))` or `console.log(isEmpty({}))` empty?

Comment: @AyushGupta `console.log(isEmpty({}))` should be return true for empty, I fixed the other one, typo

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check for equalities like this:

```js
const isEmpty = (val) => val === '' || val === null || val === undefined || (Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0) || JSON.stringify(val) === '{}';

console.log(isEmpty('A'));
console.log(isEmpty(false));
console.log(isEmpty(true));
console.log(isEmpty(0));
console.log(isEmpty(''));
console.log(isEmpty(null));
console.log(isEmpty());
console.log(isEmpty([]));
console.log(isEmpty(undefined));
console.log(isEmpty({}));
console.log(isEmpty({"test":"test"}));
console.log(isEmpty(["test"]));
```

Comment: can you add a test case for `{"test: "test"}` and `["test"]`

Comment: This is faster than @paulpro 's answer by 25%, so I'll accept it

Comment: Nice idea `JSON.stringify(val) === '{}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify( value )` and check if the result is either `undefined`, `'null'`, `'[]'`, `'{}'`, or `'""'`:

```js
function isEmpty( value ) {
    return [,'null','[]','{}','""'].includes( JSON.stringify( value ) )
}

console.log( 'True cases: ' );
console.log(isEmpty(''));
console.log(isEmpty(null));
console.log(isEmpty());
console.log(isEmpty([]));
console.log(isEmpty({}));
console.log(isEmpty(undefined));

console.log( '\nFalse cases: ' );
console.log(isEmpty({"test": "test"}));
console.log(isEmpty('A'));
console.log(isEmpty(false));
console.log(isEmpty(true));
console.log(isEmpty(0));
console.log(isEmpty(["test"]));
```

Comment: Isn't this pretty inefficient though? Overhead of stringifying and then looping through that array?

Comment: Great answer, but @AyushGupta 's answer is 25% faster https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYOMPV

Comment: @Albert In my tests AyushGupta's answer is about 100% faster. Still a negligible difference though, unless it's called hundreds of thousands of times.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert that to `String(value)` but before that check if it is not `null` or `undefined` to avoid error

```js
function isEmpty(value){
   //code
   return typeof(value) == 'undefined' || value === null || !String(value) || (typeof(value) == 'object' && (!Array.isArray(value) && Object.keys(value) == 0) || (Array.isArray(value) && value.size == 0));
}


console.log("False Cases:")
console.log('A => ' + isEmpty('A'))
console.log('false => ' + isEmpty(false))
console.log('true => ' + isEmpty(true))
console.log('0 => ' + isEmpty(0))
console.log('["test"] => ' + isEmpty(["test"]))
console.log('{"test": "test"} => ' + isEmpty({"test": "test"}))
console.log('{"test": {}} => ' + isEmpty({"test": {}}))
console.log('[false] => ' + isEmpty([false]))
console.log('[true] => ' + isEmpty([true]))
console.log('[{}] => ' + isEmpty([{}]))
console.log("True Cases:")
console.log('{} => ' + isEmpty({})) //true
console.log(' => ' + isEmpty('')) // true
console.log('null => ' + isEmpty(null)) //true
console.log('undefined => ' + isEmpty()) //true
console.log('[] => ' + isEmpty([])) //true
console.log('undefined => ' + isEmpty(undefined)) //true
```

Comment: `{}` should return `true`, it returns `false`

Comment: @Albert now all cases are fixed

Answer (score -1):

Try This function:

```js
function is_empty(value) {
 return (
  value === '' ||
  value === null ||
  value === undefined ||
  (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0)
 );
}

console.log(is_empty(null));
console.log(is_empty('string'));
console.log(is_empty([]));
console.log(is_empty(''));
console.log(is_empty(1));
console.log(is_empty());
```

**Updated Code Try This**

```js
function isEmpty(value) {
 return (
  value === '' ||
  value === null ||
  value === undefined ||
  (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0)||
  (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0)
 );
}
 
console.log("False Cases:")
console.log(isEmpty('A')) //false
console.log(isEmpty(false)) //false
console.log(isEmpty(true)) //false
console.log(isEmpty(0)) //false
console.log(isEmpty(["test"])) //false
console.log(isEmpty({"test": "test"})) //false
console.log("True Cases:")
console.log(isEmpty({})) //true
console.log(isEmpty('')) // true
console.log(isEmpty(null)) //true
console.log(isEmpty()) //true
console.log(isEmpty([])) //true
console.log(isEmpty(undefined)) //true
```

Comment: I've updated my question, can you update the answer?